# Regex for simply matching all words contains a certain subword in text

Tags: regex

What is the regex for simply matching all words contains a certain subword in text( word and subword could be equal) ? I've done some searching but can't get a straight example of such a regex. This is for a program that I install so it has no bearing to any particular programming language and I can use only regex.

Example:

Word:

> example

Text:

> This is **example**. It is important that parents should set an **example**.
>   **examples** help you to understand math.

Output words:

> example, example, **examples**

Comment: Should example also match if the input is `ex`?

Comment: check out this solution [refiddle](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5532710775622d65ec0a0000)

Comment: Yes ! Example should also match if the input is ex .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
[a-zA-Z]*example[a-zA-Z]*
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this solution:

```
/\bexample[a-zA-Z]*/g
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/qE3liJ/1)